# I need to upgrade 8.10 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, 8.10

Update computer to latest version but the version we have is 8.10 and it is not upgrading to version 13.10. I message I see is `"server error"`. I dont know how to update in another way.

Answer (score 4):

By far the easiest way of upgrading that box is backing up the relevant user data, creating a USB stick (or DVD) for Ubuntu 13.10 and installing a new system.

Otherwise, you would have to upgrade to 9.04, 9.10, 10.04, 12.04, 12.10, 13.04 and then finally to 13.10. All the releases before 12.04 have long reached their EOL and are no longer supported, thus upgrading to them will likely require manual intervention or might even be straight out impossible. Even if you would be willing to try doing so, keep in mind that each of those upgrade steps will take about as long as a fresh install.

tl;dr: **Don't upgrade, reinstall.**

Comment: You can get 13.10 [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/). Reinstalling also clears any bugs and stuff as well.